# Is relationship that "A is nested class in B" transitive?

Tags: c++, class, nested

I'm interested in is the relationship "A is nested class in B" transitive? For instance:

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
        class C 
        {
            //... 
        };
    };
};
```

I.e. Is `C` nested in `A` in that case? I'm looking for a formal reason (reference to the standard) explained this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested class is one defined within another class, so both `B` and `C` are nested.  nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class. This is not transitive though - since `C` is not directly accessible inside `A`, but through `B::C`.

The closest we find is:

#### 9.7 Nested class declarations [class.nest]

> 1. [...] The nested class is in the scope of its enclosing class. [...]

So, as `C` is not in `A`'s scope, it's not "nested" for `A`, but it is a nested class.